# Visual Studio won't let me open my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem. I just purchased a new laptop and installed Visual Studio Community on to it.

The code I've been writing is on a USB stick which I used on my previous laptop (which is now out of action). When I load VS it comes up with the Solution Explorer on the right but when I click on `Form1.cs`, for some reason, it tries to open it in Notepad and an error comes up saying `Access Denied`.

If I right click and select `Open With...`, select `CSharp Editor (Default)` it says "The Operation Could Not Be Completed"

I've registered my product as I thought that might be an issue but no matter what I try it won't open my project! What has happened and how do I get my project back?

Comment: Is the problem with Visual Studio or with the file permission? Did you try working with fresh project?

Comment: have you open VS in Administration mode?

Comment: Yes but it still tries to open it up in Notepad

Comment: If I try to view the code it says "Access to the path 'f:\app1\app1\form1.cs' is denied

Comment: Open the propertied of the cs file, is it readonly, protected... etc

Comment: Try open 'f:\app1\app1\form1.cs' in the windows explorer, if you can't open, it's a permission problem, try open in your old laptop and give all users permission (and verify if it's not encrypted)

Comment: I have the HDD formatted as its a SSD and put it in this one, so I no longer have the laptop.

Comment: Doesn't look like programming problem

Comment: it does have a gold padlock over the file in windows explorer. how do unlock the file then, I'm worried as this is a project I have been working on the last 6 or more months

Comment: Try taking ownership of the file(s): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659(v=ws.11).aspx.